# gsub regex so that escaped double quotes are left alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like a gsub that does

```
'here is \"what\" I am "thinking"'.gsub('"','\"') -> 'here is \"what\" I am \"thinking\"'
```

ie, leaves it alone if it already is `\"` . What would my gsub be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind:

```
puts 'here is \"what\" I am "thinking"'.gsub(/(?<!\\)"/, '\"')
# => here is \"what\" I am \"thinking\"
```